# iOS Restore Product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, coronasdk, restore

I am writing in corona SDK.

I use build in function store.restore() 
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/store/restore.html

I have a problem with subscription IAP products or restore in general.

Lets say you are completely new user. With no IAP history for my app.
When I call restore, it doesn't return ANYTHING at all. So I have no idea if it didn't yet returned products or there are no products at all to restore.

I am wondering if its same with native calls?

For example I would switch to native IAP, and well I am wondering if its worth it. So If I would call restore of products there, and would have no history of products, would I get any information returned at all?

I did failed to find answer to my question either here, google or IAP forums. Probably formulating in a bad way. Anyway thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Corona does not support this yet.
It's a requested feature though and you may upvote it [here](http://feedback.coronalabs.com/forums/188732-corona-sdk-feature-requests-feedback/suggestions/7237058-call-back-the-store-restore-callback-even-if-the)

About Apple's StoreKit. When a [restoreCompletedTransactions()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) method is called, will finish the whole queue with a call to delegate's [paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran) method.